# fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h'

Tags: python, visual-c++

When I try: pip install wordcloud.

I have this problem:

```
 wordcloud/query_integral_image.c(196): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade wheel
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Your post must be entirely in English including errors. This is an English site. If you'd prefer getting help in Spanish, go to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: They [say](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/637#issuecomment-1295785635) the build with recent python versions is indeed broken on windows. It seems you should be able to download and install custom-built 1.8.1 version from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud